# How many Great and Bountiful Human Empires have existed?

Tags: doctor-who

Christopher Eccleston's Doctor refers a number of times to the "Fourth Great and Bountiful Human Empire".

**In total, how many so-called "Great and Bountiful Human Empires" have existed?**

Comment: At least 3 others, presumably.

Comment: @Richard : That much is true.

Comment: I seem to remember something that may be relevant. I dont remember when or which doctor but at some point he is questioned about how humans/earth can be destroyed if they have seen future earth and there are the empires. All of these great and bountiful empires are in our future and they have been to at least one. His response is that it can all change, I dont recall exactly, but the eventual point was that there could be many or none. Go forward from now and there would be a 4th, but go back change something and there may only be 2 or none. Subject to change at any point but 4 are recorded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### **First Human Empire = Approx 2500 A.D.**

During the K9 episode "[The Korven](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WENvtSPF7Jw)", there's a mention of hostilities between the [Earth Empire](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Earth_Empire) and the titular Korven, a race of aliens who invaded the Earth in the 2400s. It's not stated whether this Empire was specifically "*Great and Bountiful*"

### **Second Great and Bountiful Human Empire = 4126 A.D.**

> **DOCTOR:** *Ah, got it! The Ood-Sphere, I've been to this solar system before, years ago, ages! Close to the planet Sense-Sphere.
> Let's widen out. (he does it) The year 4126. That is the Second Great
> and Bountiful Human Empire.*
>
> **DONNA:** *4126. It's 4126. I'm in 4126.*
>
> **DOCTOR:** *It's good, isn't it?*
>
> **DONNA:** *What's the Earth like now?*
>
> **DOCTOR:** *Bit full. But you see, the Empire stretches out across three galaxies.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Planet of the Ood](http://drwhotranscripts.blogspot.co.uk/2008/04/4x03-planet-of-ood.html)</sup></sub>

### **Third Great and Bountiful Human Empire = 7704 A.D.**

As seen in the Doctor Who comic serial [A Fairytale Life](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/A_Fairytale_Life) #01.

[image]

### **Fourth Great and Bountiful Human Empire = 200,000(ish) A.D.**

> **DOCTOR:** *So, it's two hundred thousand, and it's a spaceship. No, wait a minute, space station, and er, go and try that gate over there.
> Off you go.*
>
> **DOCTOR:** *The Fourth great and bountiful Human Empire. And there it is, planet Earth at it's height. Covered with mega-cities, five moons,
> population ninety six billion. The hub of a galactic domain stretching
> across a million planets, a million species, with mankind right in the
> middle.*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Long Game](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/27-7.htm)</sup></sub>

### Subsequent Empires

Beyond the year 500,000 Earth appears to have abandoned Empires for some considerable time, choosing to become part of a wider Galactic Federation. There's a very brief reference to the [New Earth Empire](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/New_Earth_Empire) (founded after the destruction of Earth in the year 5,000,000) in the comic serial Agent Provocateur but that's about it.

Comment: @praxis - There is no evidence of a "Fifth Great and Bountiful Empire" (or indeed any higher number) in the show.

Comment: Gratefully accepted.

Comment: Wow. Nice finds! I wasn't expecting there to be much of a canon answer to this one.

Comment: @randal'thor - The wonderful thing about a show that's run for 50+ years is that there's an answer for pretty much everything

Comment: Great answer! Just wanted to add that the idea of a human "Empire" existing in the 2500s had already been established in a number of Doctor Who stories prior to that K9 episode, such as the Third Doctor stories *Colony In Space* and *The Mutants*, see the [Earth Empire](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Earth_Empire) article on the TARDIS wikia.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - I was looking for a reference to the actual words "Human Empire", not just "Empire" which is why I plumped for K9

Comment: Well, doing a search of the transcripts on chakoteya.net I see that Empire had been referred to as "Earth's Empire" in *The Mutants* and *Frontier in Space*, which seems like it's probably equivalent in meaning to "human empire". Incidentally it was followed by the [Galactic Federation](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Galactic_Federation) in the 3000s, which may have been a less specifically human-centric empire (so not really relevant to the question but it's interesting to see that as much as Doctor Who shuns detailed continuity, in broad strokes there is a somewhat consistent future history).